# Mac Keynote: How do I add another bend point to a curved connector line (arc)?

Tags: macos, mac, keynote

I am using Keynote 7.2 in Mac OS Sierra. I want to add a curved connection line (aka arc or curve) to my presentation but with multiple bend points. How do I do that?

Specifically, I am choosing "connector line" from the top menu.

[image]

I then want to add another green bend point to make the line curve multiple times. How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tool to use for this is the **Draw with the pen tool.**

This tool is found at the top right of the shape picker window.

[image: Draw tool]

To add a new point, drag a midpoint to divide a line and add a new point.  See the illustration below.

[image: Using the draw tool]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't make a connector, just a shape.

Comment: This answer is way too ambiguous. First, note that there are *two* types of shape objects. The curve with a green point is called a "connection line" (revealed by hover text), and you *cannot* add additional points to such an object. Separately, there is the "draw with pen" tool, indicated by the small pen icon in the upper right hand corner, which creates objects that *can* acquire additional points. These points are created by hovering your mouse over a section of the line, which induces a mid-point to tentatively appear, which you can then click-and-drag to make permanent.

Comment: You are welcome to edit it or add your own. That’s how Stack Exchange works. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Here's another tip !

You can also "double click" at the green bend point and keynote will automatically convert curve connector line to elbow connector line.

This helps to avoid other shape if you create complicated diagram.

Answer (score 1):

I like the corner tool more than the draw with pen tool, since it’s easier to maintain right-angles and it links to other shapes, so when you move them, the corner line automatically adjusts. The auto-adjust isn’t so intelligent, but then keynote isn’t a real drafting app.

To get more midpoints I just create a small square shape the same color as the corner line and then copy and paste my corner line and link both to the square. It’s a bit of a cludge, but looks great.